# Dataframe Append multiple CSV files problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have multiple CSV files and the structure looks like this, and I want to append them to single CSV file with the name column ordering. How to do this?

csv 1

```
name value
n1    1
n2    1
n3    3
n4    2
```

csv 2

```
name value
n1    1
n2    2
n3    5
```

csv 3

```
name value
n1    1
n2    1
n3    3
n4    2
n5    6
n6    4
```

csv append

```
name value
n1    1
n2    1
n3    3
n4    2
n5    1
n6    2
n7    5
n8    1
n9    1
n10   3
n11   2
n12   6
n13   4
```

Comment: You can use  pandas [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append) to combine DataFrames (read from csv file) to one DataFame that can be sorted based on column `name` using [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following:

```
(pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)
   .assign(name=lambda d: ['n%s' % (i+1) for i in range(len(d))])
)
```

output:

```
   name  value
0    n1      1
1    n2      1
2    n3      3
3    n4      2
4    n5      1
5    n6      2
6    n7      5
7    n8      1
8    n9      1
9   n10      3
10  n11      2
11  n12      6
12  n13      4
```